# Check database In JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

How to check database is connected or not in JPA , when the database connection is on or off after deployed application ie(While running the application)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to execute a query, such as

```
em.createNativeQuery("select 1 from dual").getSingleResult();
```

Normally the DataSource/connection pool or JPA provider will provide some sort of connection testing or dead connection resolution.

If you are using EclipseLink's connection pooling it will automatically detect dead connections and retry queries.

Comment: This is good, but doesn't work for all database types. Doesn't work for PostgreSQL for example. I am using "select 1" for postgresql. I wonder if there is some unified way which would work for all databases

Comment: I'm assuming this is using entity manager? you didn't show what em was

Answer (score 1):

Generally all the JPA implementation use some Connection Pool or Pooled Datasource (like C3P0) and these connections pools [have a configuration](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing) which tests the database connectivity before acquiring connection. Please check your Connection Pool / Datasource documentation for this setting.

Comment: In My application database connection is cut,after giving any request it has no action or it is blank and no exception is showing in my log

Comment: You mean you are opening and closing connection for every query you fire to database ?

Comment: In my application, every action depends on DB. So it should check the connection for running application correctly.